# If statement, $(this) == $("#div")

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hya,

I would like to run a bit of code only if the focused text-box has a certain ID.
Here is my code:

```
$("input:text").focus(function() {
        if ($(this) == $("#divid")) {
                //action
        }
});
```

It does not work, I'm not to sure why.

Comment: console.log( $(this) ); and you'll see why that conditional isn't working.

Comment: It would help if you posted a jsfiddle.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try comparing by the id directly.

```
if (this.id === "divid") {
    // do something
}
```

Answer (score 6):

That'll never work because each call to `$()` returns a new object.

However:

```
this == $('#divid')[0]
```

should work. Or, as Kevin B wisely suggests, just see if your element has the "id" in question.

Comment: this is probably a better idea than comparing IDs. just because two IDs are equal does not mean the two elements are going to be the same.

Comment: @jbabey If you have valid markup and you're querying elements present in the DOM as OP is, that won't be the case.

Comment: @jbabey If there are multiple elements with that ID, there's no guarantee that the one selected by `$("#divid")` will be the one that is `this` because `$("#divid")` will correctly select only the first element with that id.

Comment: @KevinB Yes I agree, though in a situation involving improper markup things are kind-of off-kilter anyway.

Comment: @Pointy Yes, your solution would definitely work given proper markup, i'm just defending your answer vs jbabey's comment. :p

Answer (score 4):

You can use jQuery's `.is` to check.

```
if($(this).is('#divid')){
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$(function(){ // insure your code is runing after document is ready

    $("input[type='text']").focus(function() { //css selector
        if ($(this).is("#divid")) { // use .is to check the jquery way
           //action
        }
    });

});
```